# VB6: Execute two command via Shell

Tags: shell, vb6

I'm trying to execute two command via vb6 Shell command. two command have been splited with " && " string. here is what I want to execute:

```
"D:\thepath\unzip.exe" -o -q "D:\7zipa.zip" -d"D:\7zipa_zip" && cmd /c echo Hi>C:\Users\AmirrezA\AppData\Local\Temp\UZP.txt
```

When second command comes to execute, It have been known as a part of "D:\thepath\unzip.exe" but when I'm trying to execute the same line above via windows Command Prompt, there is no problem. What is wrong with the line above that can not be executed via VB6 shell function?

Comment: The easiest way to do this is to create a batch file (.bat) with your multiple commands in it.  Then execute the batch file from VB6.

Answer (score 0):

The VB6 Shell() function is a thin wrapper on CreateProcess() and doesn't involve a "shell" at all.  CreateProcess() does not understand the command syntax of CMD.EXE and operates at a far lower level.

To do what you seem to think you want you have to use Shell() to run an instance of "fat old CMD.EXE" (command shell) and pass your commands to that.